# Email 'from' field been set incorrectly with phpmailer 5.2

Tags: php, phpmailer

Does not make much sense why FROM field is not been sent as it should be.

This is the code:

```
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();            

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

        //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                   
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";                
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port       = 587;                  
        $mail->Username   = "gui.desenvolvedor@gmail.com"; 
        $mail->Password   = "***";
        $address = "gui.desenvolvedor@gmail.com";
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "Guilherme");


        $mail->SetFrom("from@from.com.br", "from you");  //<------ HERE
        $mail->AddReplyTo("reply@reply.com.br", "reply be");


        $mail->Subject    = "Email enviado pelo site.";         
        $mail->AltBody    = $mensagem;              
        $mail->MsgHTML($mensagem);

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Mailer Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {    
            echo "Mensagem Enviada!";
        }
```

The e-mail I´m receiving is that:

[image]

I am using the latest version phpMailer 5.2

Comment: Check using

$mail->From = "name@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name"; 

It's working

Comment: I´m sorry but I get the same result. From e-mail is set as gui.desenvolvedor@gmail.com

Comment: Unrelated problem: You have a typo. `SMTPSecure` should be `'tls'`, not `'tsl'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your fault - You're doing everything right - but you can't do this because Gmail does not allow you to send from arbitrary addresses. The best you can do is to predefine some aliases in your gmail prefs and use those.

This is covered in the PHPMailer docs and in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460240/spoof-from-address-through-gmail).