# Jenkins Email Authentication

Tags: jenkins

Tried using GMAIL with my own domain name e.g **username@mydomain.com** (on gmail) and my own **username@gmail.com**.

The settings I used are:

```
SMTP SERVER: smtp.gmail.com 
USERNAME: username@gmail.com / username@mydomain.com
PASSWORD: password
USE SSL: checked
PORT: 465
Reply-to-address: noreply@gmail.com
Charset: UTF-8
```

I keep getting the same error for both cases and I'm positive I'm typing in my password correctly. I visited the link given below and logged in to my gmail account from the machine which is hosting jenkins but I still run into this AuthenticaionFailedException.

```
Failed to send out e-mail

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 zv11sm652492obb.24 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:519)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:79)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: I have Mailer_Plugin 1.16 and I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Did you check with a different account ?
If you're still having problems, visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password. If necessary, enter the letters in the distorted picture.

Comment: Yep, I tried with 2 personal accounts i.e user@gmail.com and one domain name one i.e user@domain.com (also on gmail). As mentioned I've tried the options listed on the link given with the error (captcha included)

Comment: I tested gmail from jenkins with no problems, check your setup and restart jenkins.

`cat /var/lib/jenkins/hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml`

`

`

Comment: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
  
<hudson.tasks.Mailer_-DescriptorImpl plugin="mailer@1.9">  
  <hudsonUrl>http://127.0.0.1:8080/</hudsonUrl>  
  <smtpAuthUsername>youraccount@gmail.com</smtpAuthUsername>  
  <smtpAuthPassword>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=</smtpAuthPassword>  
  <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>  
  <useSsl>true</useSsl>  
  <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>  
  <charset>UTF-8</charset>  
  `

Comment: I've restarted it a bunch of times as I've been installing plugins. My Mailer.xml is about the same, except for the version:


    '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <hudson.tasks.Mailer_-DescriptorImpl plugin="mailer@1.10">
      <smtpAuthUsername>amyaccount@gmail.com</smtpAuthUsername>
      <smtpAuthPassword>xxxxxxxxxxxx</smtpAuthPassword>
      <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
      <useSsl>true</useSsl>
      <smtpPort>465</smtpPort>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    </hudson.tasks.Mailer_-DescriptorImpl>'

Comment: 2 things come in mind:  
a) test command line gmail smtp auth from the jenkins machine like in: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046135/how-to-send-email-using-simple-smtp-commands-via-gmail  
  
b) what about testing with another @gmail account ?

Comment: Yep, I tried with two '@gmail' accounts, and one '@mydomain'

Comment: So test commmand line gmail smtp auth like explains in this 
[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046135/how-to-send-email-using-simple-smtp-commands-via-gmail)

Comment: That seems to work just fine. I was able to send an email using the command line

Comment: I don't know what the issue was but I reinstalled Jenkins and the email authentication started working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i too had the above mentioned issue and I updated the mail plugin to version 1.11 and now the mails work for me..I advice you do the same and see if that works :)

Comment: Yea, I added in my comment that updating Jenkins itself solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the mailer plug-in from 1.10 to 1.11

Comment: I'm not denying that your answer may be correct, but can you explain why?

Comment: I have Mailer_Plugin 1.16 and I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

In Jerkins mailer 1.10, plain text authentication is used and this is broken. The fix is available from 1.11 onwards.

This [Mailer-Issue-log-From-Jerkins-Dev-Site](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24214) has details about the issue.