# Powershell pipe string without the the CR-LF

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm a total noob in PowerShell and I wanted to pass a string containing a null character to a command (openssl here in the current working directory):

```
powershell -command "& { \"`0myemail@gmail.com`0mypassword\" | %cd%\openssl enc -base64 }"
```

The thing is I'm getting my string encoded with as if it was passed with a carriage return and a new line characters at the end of it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the output of `openssl` (and frankly, many/most Base64 encoders put a newline at the end).

If you want to just Base64 encode it directly in powershell:

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`0hey`0"))
```