# telnet smtp.gmail.com returns no response

Tags: smtp, gmail

I can't connect to my `smtp gmail` from my  unix environment,

when I do `telnet smtp.gmail.com` I get response

```
Trying 74.125.68.108...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.68.108: Connection timed out
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::6d...
```

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail requires SMTP communication with their server to be encrypted. You're opening up a connection to Gmail's server on port 465, unfortunately you won't be able to communicate with it in plaintext as Gmail require you to use STARTTLS/SSL encryption for the connection.

Try this:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

OR using Linux or OSx, you can try to use 465 with openssl.

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
```

You should get lots of information on the SSL session and the response:

220 mx.google.com ...

Type in

```
HELO smtp.gmail.com
```

and you'll receive:

```
250 mx.google.com at your service
```

From there it is not quite as straightforward as just sending SMTP messages because Gmail has protections in place to ensure you only send emails appearing to be from accounts that actually belong to you. Instead of typing in "Helo", use "Ehlo". I don't know much about SMTP so I cannot explain the difference, and don't have time to research much. Perhaps someone with more knowledge can explain.

Then, type:

```
auth login
```

And you will receive the following:

```
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

This is the word "Username" encoded in Base 64. Using a Base 64 encoder such as [this one](https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64encoder), encode your user name and enter it. Do the same for your password, which is requested next. You should see:

```
235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

And that's it, you're logged in.

There is one more oddity to overcome if you're using OSx/Linux terminals. Just pressing the "ENTER" key does not result in a CRLF which SMTP needs to end a message. You have to use "CTRL+V+ENTER". So, this should look like the following:

```
^M
.^M
250 2.0.0 OK
```

Comment: no results:
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 74.125.68.108...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.68.108: Connection timed out
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::6c...

 telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.68.108...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.68.108: Connection timed out
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::6c...

Comment: when I try to type `auth login` it closes the connection with the host ~ why?

Comment: A similar question was asked on Stack Overflow. Have you seen this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516754/connecting-to-smtp-gmail-com-via-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Not a answer,but just posting the outcomes of above suggestions.

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 74.125.68.108...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.68.108: Connection timed out
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::6c...

telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.68.108...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.68.108: Connection timed out
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::6c...
```